# Edit items in qlistwidget in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a qlistwidget in python. There are multiple random items added by the user when running the program. I want to edit one particular item just by clicking it and typing whatever I want using the keyboard. Of course this is during runtime. Is it possible to do so? Single-click or double-clicking the item?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See the [`editTriggers`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop) documentation.